# How to add Const in Magento\Catalog\Model\Category core Class with overriding Class

Tags: magento2

I need to add new Const in \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category core class how can i override core class and add Const in Magento 2.4const

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in more details.

Comment: I want to add Constant on \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category,
with overriding class

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a core class and replace that in di.xml.
But it's a bad practice.
It's better to use a plugin to change something

Plus you can add information to the class through di.xml

Please read more here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

Comment: Can you able to give example of how to add new Const in \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category core class by overriding in m2

Comment: I am able to override core class and method but not able to define Constant in on overriding class

Comment: It's just a regular PHP class. You can do anything you want. Could you please share an error message that you get when you try to define a const?

Answer (score 0):

1. create `di.xml` in to the following location

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Category" />
</config>
```

2. create `Category.php` file on this location.

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/Model/Category.php

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model;

class Category extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
{
    const STATUS_PICKING = 'picking';

  public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For reply!
I want to add Constant on Rewrited model

Comment: where and how you wan to added that? you can added that here on the code.

Comment: See code i have edited i want like this
and i need to access this const in another class

Comment: where is your code? nothing added to question.

Comment: I have edited your code

Comment: If you want to use that on another place then create the object of your new class and use that one to access that contants.

Comment: Can you able give any example code ?

Comment: Can you ask the separate question for this one, so other community member can aslo answer for this one.

Comment: You mean i can access like this?
[ \Vendor\Extension\Model::STATUS_PICKING;]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127916/discussion-between-magento-developer-and-dhiren-vasoya).